# распарсить json cписок словарей в датафрейм

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение проблемы: у меня есть следующий список, полученный через json:

```
'Sides': [{
    'ShortName': 'АО "Компания 1',
    'Type': 0,
    'Inn': '7777777771',
    'Ogrn': '1111111111111',
    },
   {'ShortName': 'ООО "Компания 2',
    'Type': 1,
    'Inn': '77777777772',
    'Ogrn': '55555555555'}]
```

цель написать функцию, которая будет передавать данные в ДатаФрейм согласно Type:т.е. если Type 0, то берутся данные из соответствующего словаря.

```
def Paintiff(Sides):
if len(Sides) > 0:
    for data in Sides:
        if data['Type'] == 0:
            return data['ShortName'], data['Inn'], data['Ogrn']

return None

for company in companies:
c = {

    'ShortName_Plantiff': Paintiff(company['Sides']),
    'ShortName_Defendant': Paintiff(company['Sides'])
    'Inn': Paintiff(company['Sides']
     'ogrn': Paintiff(company['Sides']
    }
df_raw = df_raw.append(c, ignore_index=True)
```

Попытался написать код (сверху), но получается что он берет только первое название компании и большего ничего :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего будет создать DataFrame из всех данных и отфильтровать его "на лету":

```
In [380]: df = pd.DataFrame(Sides).query("Type == 0")

In [381]: df
Out[381]:
          Inn           Ogrn       ShortName  Type
0  7777777771  1111111111111  АО "Компания 1     0
```

Также можно фильтровать список словарей **перед** созданием DataFrame:

```
In [382]: pd.DataFrame(x for x in Sides if x['Type'] == 0)
Out[382]:
          Inn           Ogrn       ShortName  Type
0  7777777771  1111111111111  АО "Компания 1     0
```